# SCCM 2012 to distribute files (not application)

Tags: sccm

I want to use SCCM 2012 to distribute some files (not application, no executable there).

I know there is a way to create a batch file with xcopy command, and create a package to deploy that batch file to the clients. However, if I use xcopy I cannot leverage the BITS functionality and other benefits from SCCM.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I can see this is an old post, but I have used SCCM to copy files in the past.

A company I worked for in the past refused to use GP for any file copy (don't get me started) so I had to implement GP files over SCCM.

Here are some examples I used.

```html
xcopy User.bmp "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures" /c /y /r
REG ADD HKLM\Software\FILE_GP /v Copy_User_image /t REG_sz /d 1.0 /f
timeout 5
```

```html
if not exist "%windir%\system32\oobe\Info\backgrounds" md "%windir%\system32\oobe\Info\backgrounds"
xcopy backgrounddefault.jpg "%windir%\system32\oobe\Info\backgrounds" /c /y /r
REG ADD HKLM\Software\File_GP /v Backgrounddefault /t REG_sz /d 1.0 /f
timeout 5
```

I had the script add the Registry key so I could use Application deployment and have the detection method look for the key as well as the file. So if a user deleted the file it would return.

The main reason for me to have the Reg Key was if you wanted to push an updated version of the file I could set the new copy script to push 1.1 to the reg key and have the detection look for that version, then I could retire the 1.0 version.

I found also for short scripts of 1 file of small size without the timeout line it would report failed immediately, if there were larger files I didn't need the timeout. The initial fail does clear after some time without the timeout line.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you chose your settings right. 
In your batch make sure that all the paths and references are relative and never absolute.

Then when you create the deployment there is a point called "Distribution Points" where you can select the deployment options for fast as well as unreliable networks. There you would have to choose "Download content from distribution point and run locally" in both cases. Then your batch would basically copy the files from the CCM cache to the hard drive.

This method should work for packages, for applications I think it would be more difficult because you cannot directly specify deployment options for fast networks there.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to avoid batch files / scripts? When deploying a package, SCCM can copy the contents to a client and execute the program. Isn't is possible to leverage this copy function? The only difference is that I do not have a "program" to execute.

Comment: I don't know any. From my point of view the main approach MS has with SCCM is that it runs setups. Many other things are possible too but it's not the main focus, so they often require scripts. It is possible to copy files via Group Policy Preferences, but I do not know if this uses the same mechanisms for efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Packages are downloaded to the clients with BITS by default. The XCOPY command would copy from CCMCACHE to final destination on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried it or not but if you have deployed any .exe file for application its ask for dependence file in that you mention your required file which need to copy and create a script to copy data from ccmcache to copy the data to destination folder. for this you can get the use of BITS and to check if the file are copied or not you can use a proper detection method.

Comment: once the script start it will copy the data  locally from one folder to other within the system. it will not effect your network.

Answer (score 0):

I used a PowerShell script for this purpose, and it works like a charm.
Create a new script and change this one-liner to your mods:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\[NETWORK PATH]" -Destination "[DESTINATION PATH]" -Recurse
```

The other way around—if you need to make a required package—could be to create a new application deployment and run this through PowerShell (`ExecutionPolicy ByPass`) and manually install from the client side; if you don't want user interaction, make it a required deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this.

Create an application and put the files you want to copy in a folder of the content, let's call this folder "FileToCopy".
In the content root folder place a Powershell script... let's call it YourScript.ps1

Program would be:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file YourScript.ps1 -WindowStyle hidden
```

The script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

## Set variables
$Source = $PSScriptRoot
$Destination = "$env:SystemDrive\PathToYourFolder\"

## Creating destination folders
if (Test-Path -Path $Destination) {Remove-Item -Path $Destination -Force -Recurse}
New-Item -ItemType directory $Destination | Out-Null

## Copy files
Copy-Item -Path $Source\FilesToCopy\* -Recurse -Destination $Destination
```

Detection for the app:

```
If (Get-Item -Path $Destination\OneOfYourFiles) {Return "Installed"} else {Out-Null}
```